# eventMouseover not working in IE8 full calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using full calendar. It is working fine in all browsers but in IE8 events are not showing up in calendar. I checked it and found that when I remove following code then events are showing up :

```
eventMouseover :function(event, jsEvent, view) 
        {
            $('.popup_book_det').hide();
            $('#det'+event.id_id).show();
        },
        eventMouseout :function(event, jsEvent, view) 
        {
            $('.popup_book_det').hide();
            $('#det'+event.id_id).hide();
        },
```

but this code is necessary...........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you might not have included the `jQueryUI.js` in your HTML. Link to that file and see if this persists. I was able to use both eventMouseover and eventMouseout on IE8 with this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/vyKSZ/ (remove the jqueryui.js from this fiddle and the error shows up on IE8).